# How to postgres 13 partition parent,child,ch-notes events

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I'm converting a Sql Server object (44 million rows/week) and event (400 million rows/ week) tracking db to Postgresql 13.2 and struggling to get right partitioning key for object table.

```
Object 
  Objguid uuid (not serial)
  Objid bigint (from sequence)
  ObjDesc varchar(200)
  ObjSize bigint
  ObjCode1   integer
  ObjCode2   integer
  Creation_time timestamp
```

(Guids are used in logs passed in for ingest for objects and events)

```
Event
  Evtguid uuid (not serial)
  Evtid bigint (from sequence)
  Objid bigint
  Evttime timestamp 
  Evtcode1 integer
  Evtcode2 integer
  Evtcode3 integer
```

```
Extinfo
  Extid bigint (from sequence)
  Evtguid uuid (not serial)
  Evttime timestamp
  Extinfo text
```

Comment: My tables are not fixed to the above.  For loading simplicity its great to just use guids in child table so I can query them back together.  That means I would have to use hash partitioning on Object odjguid. Now I lose the benefit of dropping partition if date or sequence range. ...

Comment: Just from the table definitions it is impossible to give a partitioning recommendation. It depends a lot on your queries and how you expire data. By the way, having both an UUID column and one filled by a sequence is silly. Get rid of one of them.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - queries 95%+ return  3 tables' data (gui grid grouping by object expandable to events with extinfo (notes).

queries 95%+ eventtime range filter  85% are 0 hours -7 days old.  

queries 99%+ have further filtering with equal amounts on Object data and/or Event data (Code tables <l 1000 rows, 1 has 200,000. (Users can multiselect the codes).

data retention 12 weeks of data live, rolling off older data 
hardware usage allow a hot (NVME drive) warm (SSDs) structure.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - I was hoping to use partitions for easy rolloff and hot-warm architecture support and clearly can for Event table using eventtime.  Ingest data is guids so not having to use ids would be great (is there a significant cost of joining on uuid 32 byte vs id bigint 16 byte - it wont outweigh current cost of retrieving that data on ingest but im curious if that join affect is big.  Our queries are 99%+ limited to 100,000 rows.

Comment: That information doesn't tell me much. Also, it does not contain an SQL statement or an execution plan. I think your question is too unfocused to be answered in general. Please edit the question and add: 1) the reason why you want to partition 2) the queries on the table that create the most load.